# .contains() for nested array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, charts

I have a 2D StringArray which represents a bar chart. The first dimension represents the columns (or height) and the second one the rows (or width). The last elements are the bottom om the chart.

So, if there are no elements in the second dimension of the array, the bar chart reaches its top. To avoid all the empty chart from being printed, I implemented this:

`Arrays.toString(histogramm[i]).contains("x")`

But it seems to check the whole array if an x is contained, not just the 2nd Dimension

```
//Print
     System.out.println();
     for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        //only if there is any value, otherwise lots of empty space
        if(Arrays.toString(histogramm[i]).contains("x")){
                System.out.print("      ");
           for (int f = 0; f < 5; f++){
              System.out.print(histogramm[i][f] + " ");
           }
        }
        System.out.println();
     }
```

How do I check for a value in a single dimension, and not the whole chart?

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Comment: from this code, I would not expect that it's checking the hole 2D array, since you are explicity acessing the 2nd dimention of the array, it's not even possible that the method .contains() is evaluating over the hole 2D array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To easily find x without the conversion Arrays.toString() in each stepp,
you probably better use an ArrayList instead of array[] for the histogramm.

```
List<List<String>> histogram = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

to access : histogram(x,y);

```
histogram.get(x).get(y);
```

to search all: for any existing x

```
boolean isFound = false;
// using classical for loop
for(int x = 0; x < histogram.size(); x++) {
   ylist = histogram.get(x);
   // using for each
   for (String yval: xlist) {
      if (yVal.equals("x")) {
         isFound = true;
      }
   }  
}

if (isFound) {
  // action for found
}
```

Comment: I know it's too litle but, there is a " missing ;)

Comment: Thanks, I have written it directly in the formular, without using eclipse, I hope that there are not other major errors.

Comment: You're welcome, I think it's alright.

Comment: great, works fine thanks!

I really have to get into ArrayLists now!

Comment: I often prefer arrays, because the can translated to a mathematical formula one by one, but when it goes to searchin in an unsorted array, I use ArrayList.